# Python - How to insert a specific part of a string into a specific part of another string

Tags: python

I was wondering how to  take a string and cut off one part of it and put that part into the beginning of another string

for example:

```
string1 = 'abcdefg'
string2 = 'gfedcba
```

How could I take the first four letters of string one and put them at the beginning of string2 so it looks like this:

```
string1 = 'efg'
string2 = 'abcdgfedcba'
```

Comment: Hint: Google *string slicing*

Comment: read about string indexing in the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax).

Comment: read about [string manipulation in python](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/string-manipulation-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to look into [Cutting and slicing strings in Python](https://www.pythoncentral.io/cutting-and-slicing-strings-in-python/). You will be able to solve this problem once you go through this tutorial.

**SPOILERS BELOW**

If your still stuck, here is a basic example to get you started:

```
>>> string1 = 'abcdefg'
>>> string2 = 'gfedcba'
>>> string2 = string1[:4] + string2  # prepend first four characters from string1
>>> string2
'abcdgfedcba'
>>> string1 = string1[4:] # update string1 to not keep first four characters
>>> string1
'efg'
```

In the above, `[:4]` returns everything up to, but *not* including, the character at position 4. Additionally, `[4:]` will return every character after *and* including position 4.

Answer (score 0):

`li = [0,1,2,3,4]`
li[start:end:step]
eg. `li=[2,4,5,7]`
Now, i want to grab [1,2,3] from this list
I can do that by using slicing

```
new_li=li[1:4]
print(new_li)
[1,2,3]
```

Similarly the indexing of strings also start from 0

```
string1 = 'abcdefg'
string2 = 'gfedcba'
string2 = string1[0:4] + string2 #concat 
string1 = string1[4:7]   #slice from index 4 to 7
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.